# QMake analog of cmake's "find_package"

Tags: c++, qmake

Is there are any mechanism in qmake like cmake's `find_package`?

If I need to include library installed on my system, how can I avoid to write include path and library names manually? What is the best practice?

Comment: `What is the best practice?` To drop qmake in the oblivion where it belongs.

Comment: OK, it seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 5):

If the used library provides pkgconfig .pc file, you can use link_pkgconfig in your .pro file as:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += quazip
```

If the library provides a command line utility to get the compiler flags (like 
postgresql does), then you can call it and assign add output to the corresponding variabla

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$system(pg_config --includedir)
```

If the library itself was written in Qt as well, unlikely, but possible that it provides a Qt module, like qwt does for instance. In this case you can just add to your .pro file:

```
CONFIG += qwt
```